# How to groupby on two columns and get the values of that corresponding combination from the third column in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe given as

```
        df=        col1         col2      Labels
                    x            a          abc
                    x            a          def
                    x            b          efg
                    y            b          cfg
                    g            p          def
```

I want to take distinct combinations from col1 and col2 and get all labels for that combination from Labels column.

Expected output:

```
   df2 =         col1     col2     Labels
                  x        a       abd,def
                  x        b         efg
                  y        b         cfg
                  g        p         def
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`groupby` and aggregating with `join`:

```
df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'], sort=False).Labels.agg(', '.join).reset_index()

    col1 col2    Labels
0    x    a  abc, def
1    x    b       efg
2    y    b       cfg
3    g    p       def
```

Comment: Labels is also a column in that df. So when we give Labels.agg it says invalid syntax.

Comment: Precisely as it is a column in the df, it should work fine @jennifer ? It is the column name that I am refering to there